# Como usar ReferenceEquals, Equals, GetType, CompareTo, GetTypeCode?

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como usar e para que servem os métodos `ReferenceEquals`, `Equals`, `GetType`, `CompareTo`, `GetTypeCode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue a lista :

1- GetType -> Pega o tipo da variavel Ex:

```
var teste = VariavelDecimal.GetType(); // Retorna Decimal
```

2- GetTypeCode -> Pega o código Adjacente do tipo especificado Ex:

```
   TypeCode    typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode( testObject.GetType() );
```

3- CompareTo -> Compara a instância atual com outro objeto do mesmo tipo e retorna um número inteiro que indica se a instância atual precede, segue ou ocorre na mesma posição na ordem de classificação como o outro objeto Ex:

```
var compareValue = theDay.CompareTo(DateTime.Today);
```

4-ReferenceEquals -> Indica se dois objetos possui a mesma referencia Ex :

```
    // Create two reference type instances that have identical values.
    TestClass tcA = new TestClass() { Num = 1, Name = "New TestClass" };
    TestClass tcB = new TestClass() { Num = 1, Name = "New TestClass" };

    Console.WriteLine("ReferenceEquals(tcA, tcB) = {0}",                                        Object.ReferenceEquals(tcA, tcB)); // false
```

Este exemplo a cima foi retirado da : http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd183759.aspx

5- Equals -> Verifica se o objeto especificado é igual ao objeto atual Ex:

```
  Person person1a = new Person("John");
  Person person1b = person1a;
  Person person2 = new Person(person1a.ToString());

  Console.WriteLine("Calling Equals:"); 
  Console.WriteLine("person1a and person1b: {0}", person1a.Equals(person1b));               
  Console.WriteLine("person1a and person2: {0}", person1a.Equals(person2));  

  Console.WriteLine("\nCasting to an Object and calling Equals:");
  Console.WriteLine("person1a and person1b: {0}", ((object) person1a).Equals((object) person1b));
  Console.WriteLine("person1a and person2: {0}", ((object) person1a).Equals((object) person2));
```

Exemplo a cima foi tirado da : http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Muito obrigado cara pela lista, muito útil, abraço !

Answer (score 1):

## [`ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx)

Compara duas referências para objetos e devolvem `true` se forem iguais.

## [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)

Compara dos objetos e verifica se são iguais.

## [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Obtém o tipo da classe de um objeto.

## [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)

Compara dois objetos de acordo com um valor (como uma propriedade, por exemplo) que pode ser definido pelo programador, se o objeto for complexo.

## [`GetTypeCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.type.gettypecode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Equivalente ao `GetType`, mas traz uma enumeração ao invés de um valor de tipo.